# Regular expression operations in Python

Tags: python, regex

How to get what I want? For example, I have a string like this

```
'RC00001  C00003_C00004RC00087  C00756_C01545RC01045  C06756_C03485'
```

I want to get

```
'RC00001  C00003_C00004','RC00087  C00756_C01545','RC01045  C06756_C03485'
```

What should I do? I have tried many times, but I failed. Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what you have tried and explain why it is not meeting your expectation. Also, explain exactly what criteria you want to manipulate the string. It seems like you are removing RC###?

Answer (score 3):

```
answer=[]
a="RC00001  C00003_C00004RC00087  C00756_C01545RC01045  C06756_C03485"
b = a.split("RC")
for i in b[1:]:
    answer.append("RC%s" % (i))

print(answer)
```

This will output:

`['RC00001  C00003_C00004', 'RC00087  C00756_C01545', 'RC01045  C06756_C03485']`

Comment: Thank you. I have a try.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve this using regex, you could try the following

```
import re
input_str = 'RC00001  C00003_C00004RC00087  C00756_C01545RC01045  C06756_C03485'
pattern = '(RC[\d+]+\s+C[\d]+_C[\d]+)'
print(re.findall(pattern, input_str))
# output
# [('RC00001  C00003_C00004', 'RC00087  C00756_C01545', 'RC01045  C06756_C03485')]
```

provided the format is always RC{numbers} C{numbers}